# Usage and means of 向き

Tags: grammar, usage

The following sentences are difference usage of 向き which have different meanings. Why do they differ?

この本は初心者向きである。
This book is suitable for beginners.

逆さまに向きを変えてください。
Please turn over.

Answer (score 3):

The first "向き" is a suffix based on the verb 向く , the second is a noun whose origin is the same verb.

"この本は+初心者+向き+である" is "this_book+beginners+for+is"

"逆さまに+向き+を+変えて+ください" is "around+the_orientation+object_particle+change+please"